# Nuget Packages for the Xamarin Cross-Platform Shared Project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget, nuget-package

Right clicking on the Shared Project in a Cross-Platform solution, the "Manage NuGet Packages" menu option is disabled. Using the "NuGet Package Manager for Solution", it doesn't show the Shared Project as a project available to install to. Is the Shared Project not extendable? Do the packages have to be manually installed?

Comment: Maybe this comment will not be helpful for your, but is there any reason why you need to use "shared project", and not PCL or .NET Standard library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [shared project](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/shared_projects/) is just a collection of source files that are included in another "parent" project.  You can't compile it directly, or add references, or packages.  It inherits its environment (including packages) from whatever parent project is active at compile time.

Comment: In writing shared code, are you then limited to using extensions of packages that can be installed to all the platforms? Example, OData is installed to all platforms, can I write shared code using OData? Does the compiler build a shared code binary for each platform? Create a platform redirection table for a single library? Create platform specific branches in the shared code?

Comment: @MarcGeorge you are not limited to anything. However if you use the code that requires the package that is not available in another platform, that code won't compile unless you install some package there, or use #if directive to remove it from compiling..

Answer (score 1):

To install a package, the project must have a target. It is necessary because packages aren't compatible with every target. Shared project doesn't have any target and may be shared with various projects that have different targets and thus package may not work on all of them.

Comment: Are Nuget packages now tagged as being cross-platform compatible and thus usable with the Shared Project? Or are they totally not extendable?

Comment: Nuget packages may cover multiple platforms, but that doesn’t mean that they cover all platforms you can think of (especially not legacy platforms). And they don’t have to, they can cover just one platform.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the Shared Project not extendable? Do the packages have to be manually installed?
>   In writing shared code, are you then limited to using extensions of packages that can be installed to all the platforms?

Just as Jason said, Shared Projects are basically just a folder with your code files. They don't build any output like other project types you are used to. Whatever is in them gets linked into the projects that reference it.

To resolve the nuget package for shared project, you **should add the NuGet packages to your iOS/Android/Windows projects instead of your shared project**.

In this case, when you build the solution, the Shared Project code will have access to the iOS/Android/Windows projects.

For tracking this issue, you can refer to this thread: [Add NuGet Packages is disabled](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70403/add-nuget-packages-is-disabled)

Comment: Leo, would I be correct in saying that if one needs to have a NuGet package(s) "added" to a Shared Project, then it would be best to have a separate project to which you'll add the NuGet package(s) that's in the same solution as the Shared Project?